# entities and their properties from Active Document in Autocad

Tags: c#, autocad

I need to get all entities and their properties from model space or paper space in Autocad 2011 by using Autocad .NET API. Does anybody can help me with this question?

Comment: Do you have the Download of AutoCAD 2011 ObjectARX SDK? Maybe it can help, looking the source code of the examples. http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550